# label word wrapping within a html table cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Fragment of code -

```
HtmlTableCell fixedDataCell = new HtmlTableCell();
fixedDataCell.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "22px");
fixedDataCell.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "100px");
fixedDataCell.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontSize, "small");
fixedDataCell.NoWrap = true;

Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQRSTUVWXYZ";
lbl.Width = 1;

fixedDataCell.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

The cell expands instead of truncating or adding an ellipsis to the label's Text. It's important that the cell remain at a certain width. How to do I handle the label within that cell?

EDIT: Apparently just adding a width value will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the overflow try with:

```
fixedDataCell.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.OverflowX, "hidden");
```

While, to have ellipsis:

```
fixedDataCell.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.OverflowX, "ellipsis");
```

Comment: It will work with the width style, as per your original request. Are you sure you have tried with the code you have posted?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently just adding a width value will fix this.

Comment: I am adding a width to the table cell, not the label within the cell

Answer (score 0):

HTML would only wrap a logical word such as those separated by space or punctuation, for long-spelling words, HTML would not break or wrap the word.  So the content would bleed or force-expand the container if the container is "narrower" than the required horizontal space for the word, which is true in your example.

By adding CSS attribute such as "overflow-x: hidden", the bleeding content would be clipped to fit the container, but you may want to add tooltip in case the user would like to see the clipped content.

I would caution the usage of "overflow-x: ellipsis" as it is a CSS3 attribute which may not be supported in older versions of IE.